# Forwarding template taking precedence over overload

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

I thought that a non-template would always take precedence over a template, if the arguments match up just as well.

But:

```
template <typename... Args>
void Trace(Args&&... args)
{
    throw "what the frak";
}

void Trace(const int&)
{}

int main()
{
    Trace(42);
}
```

[This throws](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cf1cf2a0ebe089aa) unless I make the non-template `Trace(int)` or `Trace(int&&)`, i.e. not taking a const ref.

It's kind of annoying because I want to provide a different implementation for specific argument types where the real implementation of the template does not make sense (and, in fact, would not compile).

I can fix it by making the second function a specialisation, but only if I match argument types by taking an rvalue reference:

```
template <>
void Trace(int&&)
{}
```

And, well, maybe I didn't want to do that! Maybe I want to call it with a `const` thing sometimes and would rather not specialise twice.

Is it correct and standard-abiding that simply providing a non-template overload works this way, in this example? It's the first time I've noticed this behaviour (not that that necessarily means anything!).

Comment: `template <typename... Args>
void Trace(const Args&... args)
{
    throw "what the frak";
}`?

Comment: @Jarod42 But I wanted the forwarding for that version :(

Comment: "a non-template would always take precedence over a template." **Only** all other things being equal. You may want to google *"too perfect forwarding"*.

Comment: [doc about overload resolution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution#Best_viable_function)

Comment: *""a non-template would always take precedence over a template.""* There is 3 other points before that tie breaker rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`42` is an rvalue of type `int`, therefore it binds more closely to `int&&` rather than `const int&`. This is why it is calling your template `Trace` function.

If you were to call

```
const int i{};
Trace(i);
```

then your `Trace(const int&)` overload would be invoked.

---

Possible workarounds:

- Add a `Trace(int&&)` overload that invokes `Trace(const int&)`. You might also need a `Trace(int&)`;
- Use SFINAE on the templated `Trace` to prevent instantiation when the first argument is an `int`;

  ```
  template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
  auto Trace(Arg&& arg, Args&&... args)
      -> std::enable_if_t<!std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<Arg>, int>>
  {
      throw "what the frak";
  }
  ```
- Change the templated `Trace` to take `const Args&...` instead.

Comment: Meh ok guess the "non-template comes first" rule is much stricter than I thought

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: my understanding is that rule applies if the instantiation of a template would have the same priority as non-template, but if the template is a better match, it will be taken

Comment: Okay. In addition, I guess I wasn't considering that this was a better match, though now that you mention it I suppose it's kinda obvious otherwise loads of things wouldn't work (move constructors, for a start :D)

Comment: `void Trace(int)` is another simple option -- as a substitute for `void Trace(int const&)` (though the real example probably uses types you care about copying willy-nilly, so maybe not)