# Copying child class to parent class while parent class has other constructors

Tags: c++, inheritance

I have problem copying `struct a` to `struct b`. If I remove my own made constructors it will compile though. What constructor am I missing to copy construct?

```
#include <array>

using f_t = float;

struct a {
    f_t x;
    a() : x(0) {}
};

struct b : public a, public std::array<f_t, 2> {

    b() {}

    b(const a& a_) : a(a_) {}

    b(a&& a_) : a(std::move(a_)) {}

    template <typename ...T>
    b(const T&... list) : std::array<f_t, 2>{list...} {}

    template <typename ...T>
    b(T&&... list) : std::array<f_t, 2>{(f_t)std::move(list)...} {}

};

int main() {
    a x;
    b y = x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: https://godbolt.org/z/6M8T5M. There is no conversion from `a` to `float`. What do you not understand about it? If you wonder why the constructor with _forwarding reference_ parameter gets priority, read https://stackoverflow.com/q/57888165/580083.

Comment: It picks wrong constructor. Why does it not pick the b(a&&) constructor to allow copying?

Comment: Editted my comment to provide the link. BTW, you can cast your argument to `const a&` to resolve the issue: https://godbolt.org/z/sPjKzz.

Comment: Yea thanks for the help, I got it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by using `concept`

```
#include <array>

using f_t = float;

struct a {
    f_t x;
    a() : x(0) {}
};

template <typename T>
concept a_t = std::is_same<T, f_t>::value;

struct b : public a, public std::array<f_t, 2> {

    b() {}

    b(const a& a_) : a(a_) {}

    b(a&& a_) : a(std::move(a_)) {}

    template <a_t ...T>
    b(const T&... list) : std::array<f_t, 2>{list...} {}

    template <a_t ...T>
    b(T&&... list) : std::array<f_t, 2>{(f_t)std::move(list)...} {}

};

int main() {
    a x;
    b y = x;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Then, why not simply `b(f_t&&... list) : ...` instead of `template <a_t ...T> b(T&&... list) : ...`, if you force `T` to be `f_t`?

Comment: This was just an example for other thing I need and this solved it. Thing is I need dynamic types, not just floats.